# What is the logic behind "compute()" in Dask dataframes?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I'm struggling to understand when and when not to use `compute()` in Dask dataframes. I usually write my code by adding/removing `compute()` until the code works, but that's extremely error-prone. How should I use `compute()` in Dask? Does it differ in Dast Distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core idea of delayed computations is to delay the actual calculation until the final target is known. This allows:

- increased speed of coding (e.g. as a data scientist, I don't need to wait for every transformation step to complete before designing the workflow),
- distribution of work across multiple workers,
- overcoming resource constraints of my client, e.g. if I am using a laptop with limited memory, I can run heavy computations on dask workers that are in the cloud or another machine with more resources,
- better efficiency if the final target requires only some tasks to be done (e.g. if the final calculation requires only a subset of the dataframe, then dask will load only the relevant columns/partitions).

Some of the alternatives to calling `.compute` are:

- `.visualize()`: this helps visualize the task graph. The DAG can become hairy when there are lots of tasks, so this is useful to run on smaller subsets of the data (e.g. only loading two/three partitions of the dataframe)
- using `client.submit`: this launches computations right away providing you with a `future`, an object that refers to results of a task being computed. This gives the advantages of scaling work across multiple workers, but it can be a bit more resource intensive (since dask doesn't know the full workflow, it might run computations that are not needed to achieve the final target).

With regards to `distributed`, I don't think there is a difference except for where the result will be: `dask.compute` will put the result in local machine, while `client.compute` will keep the result on a remote worker.

Comment: Let's say that I load from parquet a Dask dataframe and then I use this dataframe in a scikit learn random forest classifier. How will I know that I need to do a `compute()` or not before I run the random forest?

Comment: If the library expects a pandas dataframe, then you have two options: 1) compute; 2) run the library on every partition individually. Sometimes neither option is appropriate, then you need specialised libraries that implement additional logic for computations, e.g. for sklearn you want to use `dask-ml`.

Comment: How do you know in option #1 that you should use compute?

Comment: Without `.compute`, we are working with `dask.dataframe`, so if the process expects `pandas.dataframe` we can convert dask to pandas using `.compute`... assuming that this object fits into memory. Some libraries don't need pandas, e.g. xgboost will work with dask arrays/dataframes.

Comment: If I read a Dask dataframe from parquet, and use a Dask dataframe in `dask-ml` do I need to use compute?

Comment: Nope, it will be done behind the scenes when you run appropriate command (e.g. `.fit` or `.transform`).

Comment: Therefore, if I apply a Dask function to a dataframe, and I need the dataframe data to be available to a non-Dask function, such as print, I need to do a compute(), else Dask will do it behind the scenes, is that a correct assumption?

Comment: It should always work, but for some popular functions, dask has built-in optimizations. For example, running `len(df)` or `df.head()` will make dask use resources efficiently (so it won't compute the full df, only the relevant bits).

Answer (score 1):

Each partition in a Dask DataFrame is a Pandas DataFrame.

`compute()` combines all the partitions (Pandas DataFrames) into a single Pandas DataFrame.

Dask is fast because it can perform computations on partitions in parallel.  Pandas can be slower because it only works on one partition.

You should avoid calling `compute()` whenever possible.  It better to have the data spread out in multiple partitions, so it can be processed in parallel.

In rare cases you can compute to Pandas (e.g. when doing a large to small join or after a huge filtering operation), but it's best to learn how to use the Dask API to run computations in parallel.